# Error en preg_replace, PHP

Tags: php, html

Estoy usando esta linea de código :

`$routerPattern = "#^" . preg_replace('/\\\:[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+/', '([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)', preg_quote($route)). "$#D";`

En mi código PHP para un programa, esta función debe usar expresiones regulares para encontrar este carácter `':'`.

El editor de texto enriquecido (Visual Studio Code) me da error sintáctico en las comillas que rodean a las expresiones regulares, y no entiendo por qué, ya que está aparentemente escrito de la forma correcta.

El error es real y no tema del editor de texto, ya que al insertar esta línea, el código PHP deja de funcionar.

Creo que es por culpa de `'/` ya que el carácter puede estar escapando.

El caso es que no se cómo solucionarlo. ¿Alguien podría decirme en que estoy fallando? Gracias.

Comment: Que quieres reemplazar? solo este `:` ?

Comment: Sí, quiero quitar `:` de la ruta que recibo que es /carpeta/:variable.

Comment: aparte de `:` que mas necesitas reemplazar? es para armarte bien la regla

Comment: Nada más, sólo eso